# Redirecting output from syslog to own log

Tags: linux, debian, logging, syslogd

I'm following this tutorial: [Using Fail2ban To Block Wrong ISPConfig Logins](http://www.howtoforge.com/using-fail2ban-to-block-wrong-ispconfig-logins), but rsyslog won't redirect the output from a file to another:

**/etc/rsyslog.d/12-ispconfig.conf**:

```
if $programname == 'ispconfig' then /var/log/ispconfig.log #the file exists
```

Despite this line, I keep getting the output to `syslog`:

> ispconfig[1117]: Login failed for user asdasd on IP XX.XX.XXX.XX

```
-rw-r--r--  1 syslog adm        0 Sep 12 16:13 ispconfig.log
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This may be stupid questions, but do you have `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, and did you restart rsyslog after creating `/etc/rsyslog.d/12-ispconfig.conf`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't had the `$IncludeCo....` so I added it at the end of the config file and `invoke-rc.d sysklogd restart` but still no effect

Comment: Just to be sure, try `/etc/init.d/sysklogd stop && /etc/init.d/sysklogd start` instead. Check `/var/log/syslog` for errors or warnings upon `syslogd` startup.

Comment: On my ubuntu server its `sysklogd`, and I get no error upon any restart

Answer (score 3):

@w0rldart
in your question you write

> but rsyslog won't redirect the

in another post you write

> ubuntu server its sysklogd

what is true then?

for rsyslogd is goes like this

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/log-all.conf:
:programname, isequal, "ispconfig" /var/log/ispconfig.log
# optionally you can clear this from the original to avoid the line being logged twice
:programname, isequal, "ispconfig" ~
```

restart rsyslogd

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get @toh's answer to work on Ubuntu 13 - turns out the file has to be called something like 25-ispconfig.conf. It processed log-all.conf, or at least showed errors when I deliberately wrote rubbish in it. It started logging to the new file, but it wouldn't stop logging to syslog as well.

Had to do this in 25-dnsmasq.conf:

```
:programname, contains, "dnsmasq" /var/log/dnsmasq.log
& ~
```

Couldn't make a comment without having 50 rep, so I'm posting an answer.

Just got to work out how to rotate the files now so I don't get huge monster log files growing in my /var/log

Comment: The files in /etc/rsyslog.d get executed in collating order, so you need a prefix to get it to execute before other files that may need the log set first, and after files that may set logging differently for a broader class.