# Is there a standard way of redirecting syslog events to the terminal?

Tags: linux, syslog

Say I have a program which is a source of syslog events that I'd like to observe.  Is there a standard way to run the program while sending the syslog events to its controlling terminal?  Answers to similar questions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/474454/redirecting-output-from-syslog-to-own-log) involve modifying the syslog configuration files, but it's common to have permissions to run a program yet lack permissions to see syslog output, let alone change syslog configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something like:

```
tail -f /path/to/logfile | egrep yourProgramName
```

Comment: Makes sense, but in my environment (and this seems to be a common situation) I can run processes that write to /path/to/logfile but I can't read that file.  For example I can run `logger "hello world"` but I can't observe my message being logged.  Maybe that's by design.